# Why is this program crashing?

Tags: c, variables, arguments

This function should return a string that contains string representations of the second and subsequent arguments, each to two decimal places and separated by commas. The first argument is a count of the number of arguments that follow. I did some research and found out about `va_list` and tried to work with it. Unfortunately the program is crashing and I have no idea why. I'm posting this hoping that someone could maybe spot an obvious mistake or something like that.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

char *to_string(int count,...)
{
     int i,x,k=0;
     float tmp;
     va_list valist;
     va_start(valist, count+1);
     char comma=',';
     char buffer[count*6];
     for(i=0;i<count;i++)
     {
        tmp=va_arg(valist, double)*100;
        x=tmp/100.0;
        k+=4;
        snprintf(buffer + k, "%C",comma);
        k++;
        snprintf(buffer + 1, "%.2f", x);
     }
     va_end(valist);
     printf("%s", buffer);
     return buffer;
}

int main()
{
   to_string(2,3.14876,6.123243);
}
```

Comment: `return buffer;` for a local variable which goes out of life. Undefined behaviour from there.

Comment: `va_start(valist, count+1);` should be `va_start(valist, count);`.  Go re-read the specification of [`va_start()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/va_start.html).

Comment: Strangely, OP makes no use of the function return value.

Comment: @WeatherVane: it doesn't get that far; the UB starts much earlier than that.

Comment: The statement pair `tmp=va_arg(valist, double)*100;
        x=tmp/100.0;` is curious; I don't see how it is different from `x = va_arg(valist, double);` which is simpler to understand.  The increment `k += 4;` is premature; it means the first 4 bytes of the array are uninitialized.  The use of `%C` is a POSIX-ish extension equivalent to `%lc`, but `comma` is not a `wchar_t` (but you probably get away with it as `char` is promoted to `int` because it is used in the trailing arguments of `printf()`.  Your calls to `snprintf()` are flawed because you're passing a format string as the length.

Comment: `int snprintf(
    char * restrict s,
    size_t n,
    const char * restrict format,
    ...
);`

Comment: Your calls to `snprintf()` are flawed in multiple ways.  You're passing the format string as the length (or, more accurately, you've forgotten to pass the length).  You're passing an `int` to `snprintf(buffer + 1, "%.2f", x);` but telling `snprintf()` that you've passed a `double` — that is not a recipe for happiness.  All in all, you've managed to get an impressive collection of defects into a short fragment of code.  If the exercise was to spot all the problems, then you've been given a pretty good set of answers in amongst all the comments.

Comment: Thanks, I will try to fix all those problems.

Comment: @WeatherVane so it's not undefined behaviour, because the return value is not used. (There are other sources of UB in the program of course)

Comment: @M.M it would be. Great comment thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in the comments, you need to read the manual pages for [`va_start()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/va_start.html) and [`snprintf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/snprintf.html) in particular, and also pay attention to memory management (you cannot safely return a pointer to a local (non-`static`) variable).

Here's a revamped piece of code that cleans up the issues identified and that doesn't crash (for me on my Mac running macOS Sierra 10.12.1 and GCC 6.2.0).

```
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static char *to_string(char *buffer, size_t buflen, int count, ...)
{
    va_list valist;
    va_start(valist, count);
    char *data = buffer;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        int x = va_arg(valist, double) * 100;
        double tmp = x / 100.0 + 0.005;
        int n = snprintf(data, buflen, ",%.2f", tmp);
        if (n > (int)(buflen - 1))
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "%s: buffer not big enough\n", __func__);
            break;
        }
        data += n;
        buflen -= n;
    }
    va_end(valist);
    printf("%s: [%s]\n", __func__, buffer);
    return buffer;
}

int main(void)
{
    char buffer[80];
    printf("main: [%s]\n", to_string(buffer, sizeof(buffer), 2, 3.14876, 6.123243));
    return 0;
}
```

Example output:

```
to_string: [,3.15,6.12]
main: [,3.15,6.12]
```

Note that there's the leading comma which you probably don't want.  That can be fixed like this:

```
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static char *to_string(char *buffer, size_t buflen, int count, ...)
{
    va_list valist;
    va_start(valist, count);
    char *data = buffer;
    const char *pad = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        int x = va_arg(valist, double) * 100;
        double tmp = x / 100.0 + 0.005;
        int n = snprintf(data, buflen, "%s%.2f", pad, tmp);
        if (n > (int)(buflen - 1))
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "%s: buffer not big enough\n", __func__);
            break;
        }
        pad = ",";
        data += n;
        buflen -= n;
    }
    va_end(valist);
    printf("%s: [%s]\n", __func__, buffer);
    return buffer;
}

int main(void)
{
    char buffer[80];
    printf("main: [%s]\n", to_string(buffer, sizeof(buffer), 2, 3.14876, 6.123243));
    printf("main: [%s]\n", to_string(buffer, sizeof(buffer), 20,
           6.67, 0.04, 8.81, 8.49, 3.50, 1.20, 4.28, 0.67, 1.93, 5.63,
           5.30, 8.43, 1.99, 4.62, 5.54, 7.21, 9.43, 2.02, 4.77, 0.29));
    return 0;
}
```

Example output:

```
to_string: buffer not big enough
to_string: [3.15,6.12]
main: [3.15,6.12]
to_string: [6.67,0.04,8.82,8.50,3.50,1.20,4.29,0.68,1.93,5.63,5.30,8.44,1.99,4.62,5.54,7.21]
main: [6.67,0.04,8.82,8.50,3.50,1.20,4.29,0.68,1.93,5.63,5.30,8.44,1.99,4.62,5.54,7.21]
```

Comment: Thanks. I just want to point out that it shouldn't round the numbers like it does for 3.14876, which gets rounded up to 3.15.

Comment: OK; then don't add the 0.005.